# How to access Active Record Object Values ? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model

I am relatively new with ruby on rails. I made a relationship called friendships, which has the following attributes:

```
user_id, friend_id, state
```

Inside my friendship.rb model file, i have created an opposite method to help me get inverse friendships:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base

def opposite
    user = self.user_id;
    friend=self.friend_id;
    return Friendship.where(user_id:friend,friend_id:user);
  end

end
```

Inside my view file i have:

```
<h1> Requests Ive sent: </h1>
<%@sent_friendships.each do |x|%>
  <%=x.opposite%><br>
  <%=x.opposite.inspect%>
<%end%>
```

Note: @sent_friendships is defined in my controller as: `@sent_friendships=current_user.friendships.where(state:'pending');`

View Output:

x.opposite:

```
#<Friendship::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd8abcf3498>
```

x.opposite.inspect:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Friendship id: 4, user_id: 3, friend_id: 1, created_at: "2015-07-01 21:42:21", updated_at: "2015-07-01 21:42:21", state: "requested">]>
```

But after calling x.opposite.inspect, how can i access specific attributes, for example just the state? If i try x.opposite.state i get the error:

```
undefined method `state' for #<Friendship::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd8a3f612f0>
```

I am confused? It clear that .state is an attribute after calling the inspect method? Help please?!

Comment: could you write down the result of this query -> @sent_friendships=current_user.friendships

Answer (score 1):

What you are returning from opposite using Active Record 'where' is an ActiveRecord::Relation which is an array like structure. So `x.opposite.first.state` should get what you want.